# ¿Porque se produce este error en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Entré a un canal de youtube donde estoy viendo un video tutorial donde hago la configuracion correspondiente del frameworks pero hay un paso donde hay que cambiar namespace del frameworks con el coamdno php artisan app:name sisventas, el comando hace el cambia pero al ejecutar el artisan serve se genera el siguiente error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with
>   message 'Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist' in /var/www/html/sisventas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729
>   Stack trace:
>
> /var/www/html/sisventas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Console\Ker...')
>   /var/www/html/sisventas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Console\Ker...')
>   /var/www/html/sisventas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\Console\Ker...', Array)
>
> /var/www/html/sisventas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->makeWith('App\Console\Ker...',
>   Array)
>
> /var/www/html/sisventas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->makeWith('App\Console\Ker...',
>   Array) in
>   /var/www/html/sisventas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
>   on line 729

No se, si es prescindible  cambiar el namespace del frameworks y dejarlo por el viene por defecto

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, tómate tu tiempo para leer [ask]. Es importante que aportes a tu pregunta un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte a resolver tu problema. Te invito también a realizar el [tour] del sitio y ganar así tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias posibles causas para que se genere dicho mensaje de error, normalmente está relacionado con el autoload, para lo cual puedes ejecutar en la consola `composer du`, aunque en teoría el comando que utilizaste también lo hace.

Otra razón puede ser que hayas cambiado el nombre de alguna carpeta, teniendo en cuenta que el autoload es sensible a minúsculas / mayúsculas, ejemplo: `app\Console` no es lo smimo que `app\console`.

Revisa también que la sintaxis esté correcta en `bootstrap/app.php`.

Por último, se aconseja ampliamente en el mundo Laravel **NO CAMBIAR EL NAMESPACE** de la aplicación, esto puede conllevar muchos inconvenientes a futuro al mantener y evolucionar la aplicación, a menos que vayas a realizar un proyecto macro que requiera mantener varios namespaces para separar aplicaciones, paquetes personalizados y dependencias. Puedo dar fe de los problemas que trae cambiar el namespace predeterminado en un proyecto no tan grande.

Si quieres aprender realmente de Laravel, puedes visitar su [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5), [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) o [Styde](https://styde.net/) (en español), YouTube no es un buen consejero en este caso.

Comment: Shaz, este comentario "se aconseja ampliamente en el mundo Laravel NO CAMBIAR EL NAMESPACE de la aplicación" se refiere una vez que empezaste a desarrollar no? Porque no veria problema si se hace al inicio de la aplicación...

Comment: No realmente, me baso en mi experiencia y en la de programadores de los más fuertes del mundo en Laravel que he tenido la ocasión de conocer. Cuando las aplicaciones han ido evolucionando se hace un poco complejo dependiendo lo que estés realizando, algunas veces tuve que incluso volver al namespace predeterminado después de un año de desarrollo.